# How do I merge two associative arrays such that key collisions result in an array of both values?

Tags: php

I have two or more array with the same key, I want to merge these arrays but keep the value.
Exp:

```
    $arr1 = array("message" => "message 1");
    $arr2 = array("message" => "message 2");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr3 = somefunction($arr2,$arr1));
    echo "</pre>";
```

I want result like this:

```
Array
(
     [message] => Array
          (
                [0] => message 1
                [1] => message 2
          )
)
```

Comment: See [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-merge.php) - [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) - [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) - Maybe even [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: i tried array_merge and array_combine, but result is not expect

Comment: [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) is what you want.

Comment: array_merge_recursive is good. thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_merge_recursive()` : merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

Example :

```
<?php
$arr1 = array("message" => "message 1");
$arr2 = array("message" => "message 2");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr3 = array_merge_recursive($arr2,$arr1));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [message] => Array
        (
            [0] => message 2
            [1] => message 1
        )

)
```

more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the values and no keys use `array_values` then `array_merge`

```
$masterArray = new Array();
foreach( $arr in $arrs ) {
    array_merge( $masterArray, array_values( $arr ) );
}
```

Comment: OP's example input and output show that he *does* want to keep the keys

Answer (score 0):

if you have an odd number of keys in one array you may want to insure all sub items are arrays

```
$arrays = array(
    array("message" => "message 1", "other"=>'message 3'),
    array("message" => "message 2")
);
$merged = array();
foreach($arrays as $array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $item){
        $merged[$key][] = $item;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($merged);
```

Output:

```
 Array
    (
        [message] => Array
            (
                [0] => message 1
                [1] => message 2
            )

        [other] => Array
            (
                [0] => message 3
            )

    )
```

Array merge output

```
   Array
    (
        [message] => Array
            (
                [0] => message 2
                [1] => message 1
            )

        [other] => message 3
    )
```